# BigCommerce theme "missing parsed template files" (TR-601)

Tags: bigcommerce

Trying to upload a custom theme to BigCommerce. Them uploads successfully, but I get TR-601. Any advice on troubleshooting theme? Or determining what's missing? I have no deleted anything from stock install.

Answer (score 1):

Update: if you are experiencing this error on upload, it could be related to an extraneous file somehow added to your templates directly. That was our case.

Comment: We're revising documentation to reflect this.

Comment: What does it mean to have an extraneous file? Do I have to list all my template files in a manifest or something? Or do you mean there was a non-template file in the templates directory?

Comment: Aha! I found it based on your answer. I ran `find . -type f -not -name "*.html"` in the templates dir and found a `scss` file that somehow made its way in there. Thanks! (don't forget that you can accept your own answers on StackOverflow)